# "Screen Blank" option does not keep the screen off when connected to external monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, suspend, display, brightness, screensaver

On Ubuntu 22.04 (issue also noticed on many previous versions), in the power settings, I set the number of minutes of inactivity before the screen turns off under "Screen Blank". It works fine when my PC is *not* connected to an external monitor. The screen turns off **and stay off** until I move the mouse. Then, I get the lock screen with the clock:
[image]

However, if an external monitor is connected, the screens turn off but only for 12 seconds, then the lock screen with the clock (see above) shows up for 28 seconds, then the screens turn off for 12 seconds, and so on.

Is there a way to fix this buggy behavior so that the screens stay off (and then, the external monitor can suspend) until there is an event on the mouse or the keyboard?

Comment: sounds like maybe your monitor is waking the PC up every 12 seconds?

Comment: Ok. Then, it is a hardware problem? Then, no obvious solution I guess.

Comment: there should be a solution, if only to get your PC to ignore the monitor's "wake-up" signals. I don't know exactly; maybe someone else who knows will come along.

Comment: I have the same issue ! https://askubuntu.com/questions/1442710/external-monitor-lead-to-screensaver-in-out-loop

Comment: @n0tis did you solve it? I note we're using the same laptop.

Comment: it was an issue with my cheap usb-c to hdmi adapter. changed it, now solved

Comment: A quite similar problem was solved by switching HDMI and DP cables: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1371993/external-monitors-dont-stay-off-when-screen-is-locked-in-21-10?rq=1. It seems that those problems are hardware-related. In my case, I've tried 3 different HDMI cables but it didn't change anything.