# External monitor lead to screensaver in-out loop

Tags: usb, hdmi, external-monitor, screensaver

***Normal behavior:***

After 1min of beeing IDLE, my laptop will show a blank screen to save power (not "suspend", just blank screen )
When the mouse is touched, the screen is back to life.

***Abnormal behavior:***

However, when my **external monitor is plugged via a USB to HDMI adapter**, this does **not work correctly**:

- After 1min of IDLE, the computer screen goes black,
- the external monitor detect the blank image, and after 2 min the monitor goes to IDLE mode,and
  this change of state **wakes up the computer** :/
- After 1  min IDLE, the computer screen goes black,and the loop continue .

I guess it an issue with my USB to HDMI adapter.
Is there a way to fix it in software ? (aka blacklist this device from waking up the computer ? )

**OS**:

ubuntu 20.04 on a thinkpad t14s

Comment: This is just a hint how disable wakeup for  USB device https://askubuntu.com/q/1190888/26246 and it can be used with udev rule to disable it only for that USB/HDMI adapter. Try it on the fly, if it works.

Comment: it was an issue with my cheap usb-c to hdmi adapter. changed it, now solved –

Comment: Good catch n0tis, Could submit an answer, if you could also add more info about this hardware: Brand, Model, `lsusb` and `lshw` related output part.